# Monitoring git repositories using prometheus

Tags: python, git, prometheus

I would like to monitor our centralized git repository and visualize them in Grafana. In the end, I want to create a chart that would have repository-name on X-axis and disk space on Y-axis (i.e. bar graph).

I am writing a prometheus exporter. I am unsure about the [metric type](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/) of the custom exporter.

If I design an exporter that returns following:

```
disk_space(name=repo1, size=10240)
disk_space(name=repo2, size=20480)
```

then I would have to define and add lots of [Gauge](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#gauge). **Is this the right way to go**? Is there a better solution? Also, I would like to see how git repository's disk space changed over time.

**Would it be better if I use [Histogram](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#histogram) metric type**?

**Should I define a single gauge and add labels per git-repository?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metrics about git repository can be tricky, see [this article about git-sizer](https://github.blog/2018-03-05-measuring-the-many-sizes-of-a-git-repository/). You may even reuse part of the project, it is in go.

Now, to answer your questions:

- gauge is the right type because size can increase or decrease (depending on compression or garbage collection applied)
- the natural way of identifying your metric is to use a meaningful name and use labels to distinguish between repo (this is the cardinality)

Histogram is better suited when you want to keep some information about what happens between two scrapes of a metric. In your case, this is not relevant because you only care about the evolution of the size and it is unlikely to spike wildly.